# wicket: how to update a form component with ajax, not the whole form

Tags: ajax, wicket

I've got a wicket dropdown choice, and when I select something, I want to update some components within the form. This is working fine using wicket (1.4) ajax.  However, it's updating the whole form including the dropdownchoice itself.  There are quite a lot of items in the dropdown list (maybe 2000) so it's not great from a performance point of view.

Here's the page hierarchy:

```
form (Form)
 |----packageDDC (DropDownChoice)
 |----pptview (RefreshingView)
 |----buy (Button)

packageDDC.add(new AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior("onchange") {
    protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
        //--snip-- update pricepoints which back up the pptview
        target.addComponent(form);  //ie the form
    }
 }
```

In the ajax debug window I can see all the dropdown choice options being re-sent every time

What I want to do is only update the pptview and the Button via ajax, not the contents of the dropdownchoice.

I tried adding pptview to the target, but it complains that RefreshgViews can't be updated via ajax.
I tried wrapping the pptview with an EnclosureContainer, but wicket didn't like that either (something about setRenderBodyOnly)
So I tried using an WebMarkupContainer (called 'pptcontainer') and setting pptview to be a child of that - but now the pptview is not updated.  Instead it says (in Ajax debug):

```
"ERROR: Wicket.Ajax.Call.processComponent: Component with id [[purchaseButton2f]] was not found while trying to perform markup update. Make sure you called component.setOutputMarkupId(true) on the component whose markup you are trying to update."
"ERROR: Wicket.Ajax.Call.processComponent: Component with id [[pptcontainer2e]] was not found while trying to perform markup update. Make sure you called component.setOutputMarkupId(true) on the component whose markup you are trying to update."
```

well these objects definitely do have this set to true:

```
buy.setOutputMarkupId(true);
pptcontainer.setOutputMarkupId(true);
pptcontainer.setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag(true);
```

So the page is not updated correctly.

What am I doing wrong?

The new hierarchy is:

```
form (Form)
 |----packageDDC (DropDownChoice)
 |----pptcontainer (WebMarkupContainer)
 |      |----pptview (RefreshingView)
 |----buy (Button)
```

Comment: You're on the right track. Not sure why pptcontainer2e is not found. Look at the page source (or use Firebug) and inspect the html element for pptcontainer. Does it have an id attribute? Does it match the id attribute of the Wicket ajax error message?

Comment: I get what you try to do and can't see quicly what is going on. However, I would also persue changing the dropdown to something more dynamic (Select2) so that you do not need to retrieve all 2000 values anyway.

Answer (score 6):

I faced same problem with popup window which content is provided by ajax call. In my case the problem was solved by changing html placeholder "wicket:container" to "div" element as proposed in this article: http://sha.nnoncarey.com/blog/archives/36

After this change generated html has correct id and wicket do not have problem to find it and replace content with AJAX response.